# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi JFrame se pueda mover aplicando eventos en una clase java?

Tags: java, netbeans, eventos, apache-netbeans, mouselistener

Ando aplicando *MVC*, así que todas las interacciones del JFrame las paso a una clase dentro del paquete Controlador. Por ello, he implementado las interfaces *MouseListener* y *MouseMotionListener*. El problema aquí es que no se mueve el JFrame, sé que hay la opción de agregarle los eventos mencionados en el mismo JFrame, sin embargo no debo aplicarlo así, porque estoy utilizando un patrón de diseño (*disculpen la redundancia con la palabra [JFrame]*).
Aquí un ejemplo corto:

```
public class Controller implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    int x,y;
    NewJFrame frame;
    
    public Controller (NewJFrame frameee) {
        frame = frameee;
        Presentar(frame);
        frame.jLabel1.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.jLabel1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

public static void Presentar ( NewJFrame framee ) {
        framee.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        framee.jLabel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        framee.jLabel1.setOpaque(true);
        framee.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(245,233,233));
        framee.setVisible(true);
    }

@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

        if (evt.getSource() == frame.jLabel1){
            x = evt.getX();
            y = evt.getY();
        }

    }

@Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        
        while (evt.getSource() == frame.jLabel1){
            int xx = evt.getXOnScreen();
            int yy = evt.getYOnScreen();
            
            frame.jLabel1.setLocation(xx-x,yy-y);
        }

    }
```

Nota: El **undecorated** está activado.
Edit: En la parte del **mouseDragged** le cambié el *while* por *if* y el *jLabel1* se movía dentro del JFrame, pero no me permitía mover el JFrame.

```
@Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        
        if (evt.getSource() == frame.jLabel1){
            int xx = evt.getXOnScreen();
            int yy = evt.getYOnScreen();
            
            frame.jLabel1.setLocation(xx-x,yy-y);
        }
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: ¿Los eventos de la vista los propagas al controlador o los interceptas? ¿Cuál patrón de diseño utilizas? Nota que hay diferencias sutiles entre [MVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo–vista–controlador) y [MVP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo–vista–presentador).

Comment: @Sal, creo que entendí la primera pregunta, todos los eventos de la vista los estoy poniendo en el controlador y el patrón que utilizo es MVC, primera vez que escucho del MVP .

Comment: @Sal, no puedo editar el comentario que hice, pero quería agregar que en la vista no hay presencia de *events*, estos *events* o eventos solo se encuentran en mi clase **Controller**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta estaba en que los parámetros que me permitían arrastrar el componente deseado debían aplicarse al **frame** y no al **jLabel1**.

```
//Solución:

@Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        
        if (evt.getSource() == frame.jLabel1){
            int xx = evt.getXOnScreen();
            int yy = evt.getYOnScreen();
            
            frame.setLocation(xx-x,yy-y);
        }
    }
```

El "error" estaba en que el **setLocation** solo afectaba al **jLabel1** y no al **frame**.

Aplicando el *mouseDragged* al **jLabel1**:

```
frame.jLabel1.setLocation(xx-x,yy-y);
```

Aplicando el *mouseDragged* al **frame**:

```
frame.setLocation(xx-x,yy-y);
```